# ggplot2 Reversing secondary y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

[graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyg0K.png)

I'm creating a graph that displays two line plots on the primary y axis of scores (scaling 0-5) and on the secondary y axis PCR results (scaling 0-45). However I need the secondary y axis to be reversed so that 45 is at the bottom of the y axis (45 = negative PCR result). I can get the secondary y axis to plot but no idea how to reverse it.

Link to some dummy data

https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/813109/redditexample.csv

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

#Read the file you want to use for a graph
data <- fread("redditexample.csv", na.strings = c("", NA))
data$V1 <- lubridate::dmy(data$V1)

plot <- ggplot(data) +
        geom_line(aes(x = V1, y = AveScore, col = type)) +
        geom_point(aes(x = V1, y = PCR)) +
        scale_y_continuous('PCR', sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = "reverse")
```

Have also tried:

```
scale_y_continuous('PCR', sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *-1 + 50))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's better add data using the `dput()` function, instead of using unknown (for us) links.

Comment: Use `scale_y_reverse`

Comment: That's worked to reverse both the axis! Will I have to add separate code for the primary y axis to keep it at the scale I desire?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to transform the second y axis variable for generating the graph and to transform it back for labelling. Using your data, I have produced the graph using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data) +
geom_line(aes(x = V1, y = AveScore, col = type)) +
geom_point(aes(x = V1, y = (50-PCR)/10)) +
scale_y_continuous('AveScore', sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 50 - .*10, name = "PCR"))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using this code and it reverses the primary y axis as well.

Comment: I have revised my answer to fix that.

Comment: Thank you for this. When you linear transform the secondary axis, it also transforms the two line plots. I want to keep the two line plots relative to the first y axis but then the scatter plot and the secondary y axis need to reverse. Really appreciate all your help. I've updated the post with an example graph from excel.

Comment: I have used your data to reproduce the graph. Please let know if this is not what you after.

Comment: Just make sure that you have updated your ggplot2 or tidyverse, as it was the case in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223408/how-to-set-the-secondary-axis-as-the-reverse-of-the-first-axis-in-ggplot/57224630#57224630

Comment: Yes! This is exactly how I wanted it. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated ggplot2 and tidyverse, my graph is still not showing as yours is? Is this the updated code above the graph?

Comment: You could check the version of `tidyverse` or `ggplot2` on your machine: `packageVersion("tidyverse")`.(Mine is   ‘1.2.1’) or `packageVersion("ggplot2")` (mine is  ‘3.2.0’). If updated and is still not working, please show your code, and graph. It would be easier to work it out.

Comment: It's working now, thank you so much for all your help! I really appreciate it.