# How to set the secondary axis as the reverse of the first axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to set the secondary y-axis as the reverse of the primary y-axis?

The function `sec_axis(trans = )` somehow doesn't recognise negative multipliers.

I set the formula as `~.*-1` and `~.*(2-4)`, the result is taking it as it was `~.` and `~.*2` like it just ignored the negative. See result 1 and 2 are the output plots.

```r
ggplot(d1_data[(d1_data$fc_date > "2016-10-01") ,]) +
  geom_line(aes(x = fc_date, y = fault), color = "orange") +
  geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = quantile(y_test,0.975)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = fc_date, y = -pred), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = -quantile(pred,0.975)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,5,10,15),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*-1, breaks = c(0,5,10,15)))
```

[image: result 1]

```r
ggplot(d1_data[(d1_data$fc_date > "2016-10-01") ,]) +
  geom_line(aes(x = fc_date, y = fault), color = "orange") +
  geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = quantile(y_test,0.975)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = fc_date, y = -pred), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = -quantile(pred,0.975)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,5,10,15),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*(2-4), breaks = c(0,5,10,15)))
```

[image: result 2]

The desired result would be the secondary axis is as the flipped primary axis.

---

Amend for comment 1:

It still gives the identical axis(as the primary) when setting breaks as c(0, -5, -10, -15). The red marks are the desired outcome.
[result 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC8l0.png)

---

FYI:

The blue and orange data are actually both *positive*, but they overlap too much so I reversed one of them(line 4) *as* it is negative(it is not) so that I can compare the peaks.

Comment: I am guessing it has worked but the breaks that you are using are positive. Did you try breaks=c(0,-5,-10,-15), by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=mpg, y = disp),  color = "orange" ) +
  geom_line(aes(x = mpg, y = -disp), color = "steelblue") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,250, 500), 
      sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*-1, name = "wt", breaks = c(0,250, 500)))
```

Please note: `sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*-1, name = "wt", breaks = c(0,250, 500)))` need to be consistent with the line: `geom_line(aes(x = mpg, y = -disp), color = "steelblue")`. It should be a linear transformation of the primary y axis.

[image]

Comment: still, the result is a plot with two _identical_ y-axes

Comment: It works as you asked on my side. Please show your data and code.

Comment: As I said, both y-axes are exactly the same. [The result in rnotebook](http://rpubs.com/cathy2017/identical)

Comment: I have attached the graph.

Comment: That's weird. I didn't change anything, just copy and paste your code, somehow it gives different outputs...

Comment: I actually copied the code and re-ran on my machine. I got the same graph. Maybe try updating tidyvers to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The formula `~.*-1` in your case is exactly what I used in the first code block in the question description.

Comment: It was ggplot. I updated ggplot from v3.1.0 to v3.2.0. Problem solved. Many thx.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an old-version issue.

**Updating ggplot2 from v3.1.0 to v3.2.0** solved the problem.

Thanks to @Zhiqiang.